# Apk upload on Google Play developer console not working

Tags: android, google-play-console

Strange problem here. I have a deployed application on Google Play. From Google Play Developer Console I'm trying to update the current version of my app with the new apk (version code 22 vs version code 21), however, upload fails with a generic "Upload error" message. I already tried to launch lint command and it builds the project without any error. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you change any package

Comment: no, package name is the same

Comment: I think you should upload a new apk file and then manually delete the previous one, then It might work..

Comment: The new apk doesn't work, I don't think this could be a strategy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By contacting the Google Support, they told us that the problem could be related to our DexGuard version. After updating the library to last version (8.1.23), we regenerated the apk and uploaded it without any problem :)

Comment: Same here. In our case the faulty DexGuard version was 8.2. After we upgraded to 8.2.14 (latest) the issue went away.

Comment: In my case. I gave the last bulid a day before it was working fine. Then How the DexGuard version would be faulty today. Also I have incremented the version number. Do they reply with a spefic answer or a very generic one ? @Nicola

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue few days before. I have solved it by just changing version code and upload it again.

Now if you upload apk with version code 22, change it to 23 and upload it again, hopefully your issue will resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's my case, the actual version code on the console is 21 and I'm trying to upload an apk with version code 23. Normally the console notifies you if the version code is wrong. Thanks anyway :)